# Product Image of Product Listing Page is Not Visible in Google Search Result Page

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, technical-seo, products

**Below are the activities, I have updated.**

1. Updated All Schema tag.
   [image]
2. Updated Image Sitemap
3. Updated robots.txt -
   User-agent: Googlebot-image
   Disallow:
4. Updated all Alt tag present in image.
5. Verified the CDN sub-domain where the image were stored.
6. Updated

Still not able to see product image on search snippet of PLP url.

Comment: Did you verify the schema is valid with the Rich Snippet testing tool from Google? Are there any errors thrown?

Comment: Yes verified all present, also attached the image of rich result test.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
"User-agent: Googlebot-image Disallow:"
```

This should be false or it is not allowed at all.
Otherwise: make sure you have sufficient permissions.

Comment: Google account manager suggested to add this line in robots.txt also given in below link
https://support.google.com/manufacturers/answer/7349854?hl=en